VimeoDotNet: How to resolve "Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error?
I have a Xamarin application running, and everything was working fine until recently. I'm using a VimeoDotNet package to interact with the VimeoAPI. However, it's starting to throw this error these days:
VimeoDotNet.Exceptions.VimeoApiException: Error retrieving information from Vimeo API. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED 

Xamarin.iOS is working fine. It's just the android application that is not working anymore. Changing the HTTPClient and SSL Implementation did not help at all. I don't know why this is happening all of a sudden. Any help would be much appreciated!

You will have to at least see into the TLS handshake packets. Please work with your network administrators to get started.

What Android version(s) do you use for testing your app? If you use too old Android versions ( before 7.1) and the used https server uses a Let's Encrypt cert then you may be hit by the end of the cross signing of let's encrypt root ca.

I'm facing this issue too on Android 13.0. I've checked api.vimeo.com and it is indeed using a Letsencrypt certificate. I changed my emulated to Android 14.0 (API level 34) and it worked.
